# Doubt about Huang's proof of Equipartition Theorem in Microcanonical Ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration, mathematics

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Generalized Equipartition Theorem in the Microcanonical Ensemble. The [proof that appears in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#The_microcanonical_ensemble) is the same that can be found in Kerson Huang's *Statistical Mechanics* (page 137 of the 2nd edition).

There is a step that I am not able to understand. After getting to the following expression

\begin{aligned}\int _{H<E}x_{m}{\frac {\partial (H-E)}{\partial x_{n}}}\,d\Gamma &=\int _{H<E}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x_{n}}}{\bigl (}x_{m}(H-E){\bigr )}\,d\Gamma -\int _{H<E}\delta _{mn}(H-E)d\Gamma \\&=\delta _{mn}\int _{H<E}(E-H)\,d\Gamma ,\end{aligned}

both Huang and Wikipedia state the following: "The first term on the right hand side of the first line is zero (it can be rewritten as an integral of $H − E$ on the hypersurface where $H = E\,$)".

I suppose that they are using Gauss' divergence theorem to rewrite the integral of the divergence of a vector field over a (hyper)volume as the integral of the vector field over the (hyper)surface that bounds the (hyper) volume. But I do not see how the integrand

\begin{aligned}\frac {\partial {x_{m}(H-E)}}{\partial x_{n}}\end{aligned}

can be seen as a divergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not strictly a divergence, but it can be rewritten as a boundary term which vanishes.  Let $M$ denote the region for which $H \leq E$. [It is known that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities)
$$
\int_M \vec{\nabla} \psi \, d^N V = \oint_{\partial M} \psi \, d^{N-1} \vec{S},
$$
or, looking at the $n$-component of this,
$$
\int_M \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_n} \, d^N V = \oint_{\partial M} \psi \, d^{N-1} S_n.
$$
Choosing $\psi = x_m (H - E)$ then lets us conclude that
$$
\int_M \frac{\partial [x_m (H-E)]}{\partial x_n} \, d^N V = \oint_{\partial M} x_m (H - E) \, d^{N-1} S_n,
$$
which (as you note) vanishes on the boundary of the region $M$ because $H = E$ there.

---

As an aside, the identity I started with above *does* follow from the divergence theorem as you know it.  If $\vec{c}$ is any constant vector field, then we have
\begin{align*}
\vec{c} \cdot \left[ \int_{M} \vec{\nabla} \psi \, dV \right] &= \int_{M} \vec{c} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \psi \, dV \\
&= \int_{M} \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\psi \vec{c}) \, dV & \text{(since $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{c} = 0$)} \\
&= \oint_{\partial M} \psi \vec{c} \cdot d\vec{S} & \text{(divergence theorem)} \\
&= \vec{c} \cdot \left[ \oint_{\partial M} \psi \, d\vec{S} \right].
\end{align*}
Since this identity holds true for *any* constant vector field $\vec{c}$, then the vectors in square brackets at the start and at the end must be equal.